# What's wrong in my if statements logic?

Tags: c++, if-statement, logic

In this little program I try to order 3 numbers in a descending order. But seems like the line in which has "// 3 2 1 - doesn't work" as a comment isn't working as expected. It seems like my logic is correct.

**My input:**
4,
554 and
454545

**Output:** (which is not what I wanted)
554, 454545 and 4

If the value hold on the integer numbThree is bigger than numbOne and if numbOne is **NOT** bigger than numbTwo (**NOT** == else) it should ouput numbThree, numbTwo and numbOne in this order, why doesn't it work?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
int numbOne = 0, numbTwo = 0, numbThree = 0;
std::cin >> numbOne >> numbTwo >> numbThree;

if (numbOne > numbTwo) {
    if (numbTwo > numbThree) {
        std::cout << numbOne << " " << numbTwo << " " << numbThree << std::endl; // 1 2 3
    }
    else {
        std::cout << numbOne << " " << numbThree << " " << numbTwo<< std::endl; // 1 3 2
    }
}
else if (numbTwo > numbOne) {
    if (numbOne > numbThree) {
        std::cout << numbTwo << " " << numbOne << " " << numbThree << std::endl; // 2 1 3 - works
    }
    else {
        std::cout << numbTwo << " " << numbThree << " " << numbOne << std::endl; // 2 3 1
    }
}
else if (numbThree > numbOne) {
    if (numbOne > numbTwo) {
        std::cout << numbThree << " " << numbOne << " " << numbTwo << std::endl; // 3 1 2
    }
    else {
        std::cout << numbThree << " " << numbTwo << " " << numbOne << std::endl; // 3 2 1 - doesn't work
    }
}

std::cin.get();
std::cin.ignore();
return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: What's wrong is that the code should use a small array, and `std::sort`, instead of this kind of spaghetti code.

Comment: That case will be caught by the first `else if` because `numbTwo > numbOne` is true.

Comment: Look closer when you might reach your third condition:

`if (numbOne > numbTwo) { ... } else if (numbTwo > numbOne) { ...} else if (numbThree > numbOne){`

You only reach it if the first two conditiona are false which means the first two numbers are equal!

Comment: Thanks Gavin and Gerhardh for point out what I was missing in my logic, really helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot, in general, sort 3 numbers with 2 comparisons (see YSC's comment for a hard reason in terms of information content). Already your case `1 3 2` is flawed: what if `numbThree > numbOne`?

In general you have to allow for up to 3 comparisons. Of course, you can simply use the sort functionality provided by the standard library (i.e. by the language). If you don't want to (for some reason), then the correct logic (for ascending order) is

```
if(a<b)
  if     (b<c) // a,b,c   // 2 comparisons
  else if(a<c) // a,c,b   // 3 comparisons
  else         // c,a,b   // 3 comparisons
else
  if(    (a<c) // b,a,c   // 2 comparisons
  else if(b<c) // b,c,a   // 3 comparisons
  else         // c,b,a   // 3 comparisons
```

Thus, in 4 out of 6 possible cases we need 3 rather than 2 comparisons.

Comment: With two comparisons, one can harvest 2 bits of information. Finding a permutation for 3 numbers has 6 possible outputs, which is ~2.58bits > 2bits.

Answer (score 1):

Not intended as an answer, but as an illustration of the comment by Sam Varshavchik:

> What's wrong is that the code should use a small array, and std::sort,
>   instead of this kind of spaghetti code.

While Sam is right about production code, as an exercise of how to implement the logic, the question is okay and there is already a solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(3);
    if (! (std::cin >> v[0] >> v[1] >> v[2])) { exit(-1); }
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<int>());
    for (auto c: v) { std::cout << c << " "; }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I understood what he said but I'm learning through a book and I must do the exercise with what I've learnt so far, that's if statements.

Seems like @Gavin 's answer is the most useful one since he really points out why my code didn't work as expected. Thanks everyone.

Comment: No worries, as I said: it isn't meant to be an answer.  More an example of how it could be done too in C++ in a couple of chapters in your book.